# Reasons why DynamoDB TTL is deleting items 48 hours early?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I was looking to set up TTL for my DynamoDB table and set it to be the "TTL" key. Used python3 + boto3 to do a batch write with the TTL field set to str(int(time.time()) + 172800). I also tried int(time.time()) + 172800.

In either case, the epoch time stamp in the TTL column was 48 hours in the future. When using the second version, hovering over the value in the DynamoDB table showed a pop up with the date and time of the time stamp and I confirmed it was 2 days in the future.

However, when I came back ~5 minutes later and refreshed the table, all of the entries were gone.

I repeated the process and actively refreshed to keep an eye on the values and they were all getting deleted gradually with later time stamps being deleted last. I checked the cloudwatch logs and they showed my scans and writes in the correct GMT time.

I'm just wondering what might cause this to happen. For reference the table's creation date was July 27, 2019; is it possible that the clock for the db is off?

Example timestamp that was deleted: 1588959677 which should translate to 5/8/2020 sometime.

Let me know if I need to provide more information and thanks for the help.

Edit: When I batch write I run the following:

```
boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name).batch_write_item(RequestItems=put_data)
```

where:

```
put_data = { tablename: { "PutRequest": { "Item" { "id": "id", "TTL": ttl_integer_value, "another_id": "id", "flag": "true", "timestamp": original_time_value, "description": "some description" }}}}
```

I tried changing it to:

```
put_data = { tablename: { "PutRequest": { "Item" { "TTL": {"N": ttl_integer_value}... }}}}
```

but it threw an error with the key value not being valid

Also, if I hover over the integer value in the table, the appropriate date and time shows in a popup. Wouldn't that be an indication of the correct format?

Comment: Is the TTL attribute of type Number or String? TTL attributes must use the Number data type (and values must be in Unix epoch time format).

Comment: Is there a way to check from the dynamodb itself? When I batch write I run the following:

boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name).batch_write_item(RequestItems=put_data) 

where put_data = { tablename: { "PutRequest": { "Item" { "TTL": ttl_integer_value }}}}

I tried changing it to put_data = { tablename: { "PutRequest": { "Item" { "TTL": {"N": ttl_integer_value} }}}} but it threw an error with the key value not being valid.

Comment: Those are two different ways of putting an item (the first via high-level DocumentClient and the second via low-level DynamoDB client). Use the DynamoDB console, browse the table, and look at an item. Is 'TTL' of type Number? I'm assuming it is, but worth checking.

Comment: Yeah, "TTL" is of "Number" type.

Comment: OK, then I would assume that you have overlooked something. There's virtually zero chance that DynamoDB is deleting items incorrectly. You'll have to double-check everything, including whether or not you have another app or a Lambda function, for example, that might be deleting items. Quick way to validate this would be to create a brand new table, enable TTL, and then write similar items with TTL to that new table.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. I only have a single lambda writing to my single table on my aws account so at least the scope of my review will be pretty narrow.

Comment: BTW is TTL your primary key value? That's unusual.

Comment: It is not, does it have to be? I have an "id" as my primary key value.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be, and it would be strange for TTL to be the PK. I'm asking because the code you wrote shows you putting an item with just a TTL attribute and no other attributes at all.

Comment: Apologies, I tried to leave out the other parts because I thought it was unnecessary but I'll edit them in incase they're useful. That being said, I tried making a new table and it doesn't seem to be expiring immediately so maybe it's a table-specific issue. I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: You can enable streaming on the errant table and write a new Lambda function that's triggered by activity on the DynamoDB table. You'll see the puts and then later you'll see, I'm assuming, the deletes.

Comment: The new table seems to be behaving correctly so I'm just going to switch over. Thanks for the suggestions and help!